# I would like to ask any idea on how to implement a login system in laravel 8

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-8, laravel-blade

I would like to ask any idea on how I can implement login system in laravel 8, which if I logged in then if the password is correct and similar in the database and the password is a default password, will automatically pop up a change password pop up modal that will change password, and if it's not a default password it will automatically redirect into landing page.

I am expecting a pure laravel 8 login system, Thank you and I hope you I gained ideas from you all.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 1):

Laravel has built in systems for authentication (login system) and you can leverage that:

Here is official documentation page on how to set up authentication in Laravel 8.

https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/authentication

Here is one tutorial on how to do it:

https://laravelarticle.com/laravel-8-authentication-tutorial

Basically all you need to do is to run few commands and that should do it:

```
php artisan make:auth
```

```
composer require laravel/ui
php artisan ui vue
php artisan ui vue --auth
npm install && npm run dev
```